# How to sort CSV file in ascending order by integer in middle of file name

Tags: python, python-re

I want to sort my CSV files before processing them. Here is the format for the file names:

```
4A085SHT_SITE12_TREE3_LAUB.csv
67E89SOIL_SITE9_TREE2_LAUB.csv
4BBA3DEND_SITE10TREE2_LAUB.csv
```

The files should be sorted by the integer after SITE, i.e. 9, 10, and 12 in the above example and neglect all other characters.

Currently, I am using:

```
for file_name in os.listdir(folder_path):
```

I tried:

```
file_names = sorted(os.listdir(folder_path), key=lambda x: int(x.split('SITE')[1].split('.')[0])) #sort by first integer after SITE (if available)
```

but this throws me the following error:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '10TREE2_LAUB'
```

So I need to somehow remove TREE2_LAUB also in that example.

Edit: thanks to @kosciej16 for the solution. For my case, I added a check if the file contains the phrase:

```
file_names = sorted(os.listdir(folder_path), key=lambda el: int(re.search(r"SITE(\d+)", el).group(1)) if re.search(r"SITE(\d+)", el) else float('inf'))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are very close! You just need to change sorting key:

```
import re

file_names = sorted(l, key=lambda el: int(re.search(r"SITE(\d+)", el).group(1)))
```

Here we are saying we want to find "SITE" and then any amount of digits. We use brackets to give a group for that digits, so we can access it with `.group(1)`

It assumes that all files satisfy the pattern. If not, you can do the following:

```
def foo(el):
    # assumes python 3.8+
    if (match := re.search(r"SITE(\d+)", el)) is not None:
        return int(match.group(1))
    # Put such elements on the end
    return float("inf")

file_names = sorted(l, key=foo)
```

Comment: I am getting following error here:     file_names = sorted(os.listdir(folder_path), key=lambda el: int(re.search(r"SITE(\d+)", el).group(1)))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Comment: That means at least one of the file doesn't match the regex. See my edited answer